What is the meaning of this complex derivative with respect to a wave function?
In quantum optimal control papers such as (Loading a Bose-Einstein Condensate onto an Optical Lattice, https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0209195) and (Introduction to the Pontryagin Maximum
Principle for Quantum Optimal Control, https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.09368), there is a an equation (equations 20, 27 in the former paper, 16 in the latter) for computing the conjugate vector $\chi$ to the wave function $\psi$ analogous to $p$ and $q$ in classical mechanics. I.e. $$\dot{\chi} = -\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial\psi}, \qquad\dot{\psi} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial\chi}$$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the "Control Hamiltonian". For a closed quantum system evolving under the controlled Schrodinger equation, the control Hamiltonian is given by $$\mathcal{H}(t,\psi(t),\chi(t),u(t)) = \text{Im}(\langle{\chi}|H_0 + \sum_j H_ju_j(t)|\psi\rangle) + \lambda \sum_j u_j(t)^2$$
where $\lambda$ is some multiplier for the control penalty and $\{u(t)\}$ is a set of real controls.
How, exactly, does one compute the derivative of this function with respect to complex variables if $\text{Im}(\cdot)$ is a nowhere complex-differentiable function? Both papers gloss over the mechanism for computation but conclude that
$$\dot{\chi} = -i(H_0 + \sum_j H_ju_j(t))\chi$$ $$\dot{\psi} = -i(H_0 + \sum_j H_ju_j(t))\psi$$
or that both follow the Schrodinger equation. The dynamics for $\psi$ are defined elsewhere in the paper, but $\dot{\chi}$ is baffling. What is going on here?

It changes from H to H(u) in the paper, maybe that means something. Also, as I remember Im is a projection operator, so not sure why you would need an analytical complex derivative, wouldn't a usual scalar derivative be enough (i.e. only time direction, not "complex time" direction).

Also not 100% sure you copied the formulas correct, I am seeing kets in the paper but not in your definition.

I had a hard time finding the definition of the undotted variables, maybe you need to integrate over time somewhere.

The derivatives are presumably (equal to) Dolbeault derivatives
$$ \begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}~=~&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial {\rm Re}\psi}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial {\rm Im}\psi} \right), \cr \frac{\partial}{\partial\psi^{\ast}}~=~&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial {\rm Re}\psi}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial {\rm Im}\psi} \right).\end{align}$$

Also called Wirtinger derivatives.

Strangely enough, the derivative with respect to the conjugate is the one giving the correct answer. Is this possibly a mistake in the papers? The derivative as stated gives an answer that amounts to \dot{\psi}_j = i H*_jk \psi*_k which is bizarre.)
